# Accumulation algorithm structure

Tags: c#, algorithm, pseudocode

I have a table where I can find transactions related to an account. 
This table contains either debit and credit transactions.

I need help on structuring an algorithm that calculates if an account has never reached a defined value (suppose 1000) in a specific moment of time.

Let's see the following samples:

```
ID     Date             Value        Type    Account
----   -------------    ----------   -----   -------
1      2015-07-23       100.00       C       1
2      2015-07-28       350.00       C       1
3      2015-08-14       250.00       C       1
4      2015-08-30       180.00       C       1
5      2015-09-22       230.00       C       1
6      2015-09-28       230.00       D       1
```

In this case the first debit transaction happened when the balance was `1110.00`. So even if now the current balance is under `1000.00` I need to consider this account

```
ID     Date             Value        Type    Account
----   -------------    ----------   -----   ---------
1      2015-07-23       190.00       C       2
2      2015-07-28       350.00       C       2
3      2015-08-14       450.00       C       2
4      2015-08-30       100.00       D       2
5      2015-09-22       100.00       C       2
```

In this case there is a debit transaction that dropped the balance before reaching `1000.00`. So I should not consider this account.

Is there any general and simply way to make this calculation?

Thanks!

EDIT: As per the comments this is what I'have so far:

```
decimal counter = 0;
bool hasBonus = false;
foreach ( var tx in txList ) {
    if ( tx.TransactionType == TransactionType.C ) {
        counter += tx.Value;
    }
    else if ( tx.TransactionType == TransactionType.D ) {
        counter -= tx.Value;
    }
    if ( counter >= 1000M ) {
        hasBonus = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do it easily with SQL.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am trying by code not by sql. However it seems to me that the code is getting a bit messy. I read all transactions with linq-to-entities and then iterate aon all the transactions to decide if I should accumulate or not.

Comment: I don't understand your constraints. Why exactly is the second account not considered? Is there a time constraint as well? Also you should simplify your examples. You don't need six example transactions to get your point across.

Comment: @Abbondanza: I am sorry for the number of examples. However you are right. Second example was a mistake and I have corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any general and simply way to make this calculation?

**With this model, no.**

IMO, the only thing that can be improved is the *usability*.

Assuming the model is like this

```
public enum TransactionType { Credit, Debit }

public class Transaction
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }
    public TransactionType Type { get; set; }
    public bool IsCredit {  get { return Type == TransactionType.Credit; } }
    public int Account { get; set; }
}
```

I would put the calculation in a helper function like this

```
public static class TransactionUtils
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Transaction, decimal>> GetCreditInfo(this IEnumerable<Transaction> accountTransactions)
    {
        decimal credit = 0;
        return from t in accountTransactions
               orderby t.Date, t.ID
               select new KeyValuePair<Transaction, decimal>(t, credit += t.IsCredit ? t.Value : -t.Value);
    }
}
```

Now a LINQ queries can be used for answering different questions including the original from the post.

For instance, let take your sample data

```
var transactions = new List<Transaction>
{
    new Transaction { ID = 1, Date = new DateTime(2015, 07, 23), Value = 100, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 1 },
    new Transaction { ID = 2, Date = new DateTime(2015, 07, 28), Value = 350, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 1 },
    new Transaction { ID = 3, Date = new DateTime(2015, 08, 14), Value = 250, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 1 },
    new Transaction { ID = 4, Date = new DateTime(2015, 08, 30), Value = 180, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 1 },
    new Transaction { ID = 5, Date = new DateTime(2015, 09, 22), Value = 230, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 1 },
    new Transaction { ID = 6, Date = new DateTime(2015, 09, 28), Value = 230, Type = TransactionType.Debit, Account = 1 },

    new Transaction { ID = 1, Date = new DateTime(2015, 07, 23), Value = 190, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 2 },
    new Transaction { ID = 2, Date = new DateTime(2015, 07, 28), Value = 350, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 2 },
    new Transaction { ID = 3, Date = new DateTime(2015, 08, 14), Value = 450, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 2 },
    new Transaction { ID = 4, Date = new DateTime(2015, 08, 30), Value = 100, Type = TransactionType.Debit, Account = 2 },
    new Transaction { ID = 5, Date = new DateTime(2015, 09, 22), Value = 100, Type = TransactionType.Credit, Account = 2 },
};
```

Answering the original question would be like this

```
decimal maxCredit = 1000;
```

For specific account

```
int account = 1;
bool hasBonus = transactions
    .Where(t => t.Account == account)
    .GetCreditInfo().Any(info => info.Value >= maxCredit);
```

For all accounts

```
var bonusInfo = transactions.GroupBy(t => t.Account, (key, elements) => new
{ 
    Account = key,
    HasBonus = elements.GetCreditInfo().Any(info => info.Value >= maxCredit)
}).ToList();
```

Other

```
var maxCreditInfo = transactions.GroupBy(t => t.Account, (key, elements) => new
{
    Account = key,
    MaxCredit = elements.GetCreditInfo().Max(info => info.Value)
}).ToList();

var bonusTransactionInfo = transactions.GroupBy(t => t.Account, (key, elements) => new
{
    Account = key,
    BonusTransactions = elements.GetCreditInfo()
        .Where(info => info.Key.IsCredit && info.Value >= maxCredit).ToList()
}).ToList();
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say you have a Transaction class

```
public enum TransactionType 
  {
    C,
    D
  }

public class Transaction
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public double Value{get;set;}
    public TransactionType Type{get;set;}
    public int Account{get;set;}
}
```

As you said, you get them from DB so that part is covered. You obtain an `IEnumerable<Transaction>`. Using the following function will do the trick:

```
public bool AccountIsGood(IEnumerable<Transaction> dbTransactions)
{
    var transactions = dbTransactions.OrderBy(t => t.Date).ToList();
    var sum = 0;
    foreach(var tran in transactions)
    {

       if(tran.Type = TransactionType.D)
       {
          return false;
       }
       sum += tran.Value;

       if(sum > 1000)
       {
         return true;
       }
   }
  return false;
}
```

**Edit**: A more optimal solution in C# is if you can pass an `IQueryable<Transaction>` instead of `IEnumarable<Transaction>` using the code from bellow you could split the transactions into bulks:

```
public bool AccountIsGood(IQueryable<Transaction> dbTransactions)
{
    var transactions = dbTransactions.OrderBy(t => t.Date);
   // transactions is now and OrderedQueryable
    var sum = 0M;
    var totalTrans = transactions.Count();
    var skip = 0;
    while(skip < totalTrans)
    {
       foreach(var tran in transactions.Skip(skip).Take(100).ToList())
       {

          if(tran.Type = TransactionType.D)
          {
             sum -= tran.Value;
          }
          else
          {
             sum += tran.Value;
          }

          if(sum > 1000M)
          {
            return true;
         }
       }
     }
     skip += 100;
   }
 return false;
}
```

A more improved solution would be if you could move this in database, removing the trips to DB over and over again

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. I dont think this will work as I need. Maybe I have'nt been clear in the question. A debit transaction shall reset the sum, a user in fact can make a debit transaction and after that make many credits to reach the value. This can be simply said as, in a specific moment, the account balance is greater or equal to 1000.

Comment: ok. If the account balance is 900 and the user makes a debit transaction of 150 the balance will be 750 right? if after that the user makes a credit transaction of 300 the balance will be 1050 meaning it went over 1000 and the account is good? or after the Debit, balance should reset to 0 and recalculate for next transactions?

Comment: The first. Please have a look at my question edit. I have posted my actual solution (which for instance is about the same as yours). The only problem I was thinking is that this algorythm can take time as the number of transactions increase. I was looking for a more elengant and maybe easier solution.

Comment: `Skip` and `Take` in the `IQueryable` scenario make no any sense to me. The `OrderBy` will happen at the db side, and the resulting **enumerable** can just be `foreach`-ed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution using LINQ:

```
var transactions = new[]
                    {
                        new { Value = 100.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 1 },
                        new { Value = 350.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 1 },
                        new { Value = 250.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 1 },
                        new { Value = 180.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 1 },
                        new { Value = 230.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 1 },
                        new { Value = 230.0, IsCredit = false, Account = 1 },
                        new { Value = 190.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 2 },
                        new { Value = 350.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 2 },
                        new { Value = 450.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 2 },
                        new { Value = 100.0, IsCredit = false, Account = 2 },
                        new { Value = 100.0, IsCredit = true, Account = 2 },
                    };

var bonusStatusOfAccounts = transactions.GroupBy(
    t => t.Account,
    t => t,
    (account, accountTransactions) =>
    new
        {
            Account = account,
            HasBonus = accountTransactions.Aggregate(
                new { AccountBalance = 0.0, HasBonus = false },
                (state, t) =>
                    {
                        var newBalance = state.AccountBalance + (t.IsCredit ? t.Value : -t.Value);
                        return new
                            {
                                AccountBalance = newBalance,
                                HasBonus = state.HasBonus || newBalance >= 1000
                            };
                    },
                state => state.HasBonus)
        }).ToList();
```

By grouping the transactions initially by account, we then have an IEnumerable per account of transactions which has enough information to figure out if HasBonus should be true.

The generalised form of Aggregate() takes three arguments:

1. A starting state (in this case the account balance is initially zero and HasBonus is false)
2. A delegate to "add" one transaction to this state (here I calculate the new balance and set HasBonus if it's >=1000)
3. A delegate to take the final state and get the answer we want from it (here just by getting the HasBonus flag)

By tweaking the logic in the second delegate, you can control exactly under which conditions you award the bonus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have never used the group by linq extension. I need to compare it regarding performance even if I suspect that will be better than my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks just fine to solve your problem. However, inside your loop you should break as soon as you have hit the ballance threshold, in order to avoid superfluous computations:

```
if ( counter >= 1000M ) {
    hasBonus = true;
    // Stop iterating through transactions.
    break;
}
```

The real key to solving your problem with good performance lies in the way how you read your transaction data and how you make it accessible to other components.

Make sure you return you transactions as an `Enumerable` and use `yield return ...` to return a single transaction from your read loop.

When you are using Entity Framework you don't have to worry about this as long as you don't execute `ToList()`, `ToArray()`, `Count()` or something similar that materializes the transaction collection somewhere earlier in your code.

Comment: And what are the benefits of this implementation compared to the OP provided code (assuming he adds a `break;` after `hasBonus = true;` line)? Because what I see is - less efficient (involves delegates and closures), less readable.

Comment: @IvanStoev, well that's true. I'll remove the code. The most important thing is actually the last paragraph where I talk about enumerating the transactions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. thanks for suggestion on the break, I forgot it!